# Treetop backtracking similar to regex?

Tags: ruby, treetop, peg

Everything I've read suggests Treetop backtracks like regular expressions, but I'm having a hard time making that work.

Suppose I have the following grammar:

```
grammar TestGrammar
  rule open_close
    '{' .+ '}'
  end
end
```

This does not match the string `{abc}`. I suspect that's because the `.+` is consuming everything from the letter `a` onwards. I.e. it's consuming `abc}` when I only want it to consume `abc`.

This appears different from what a similar regex does. The regex `/{.+}/` will match `{abc}`. It's my understanding that this is possible because the regex engine backtracks after consuming the closing `}` as part of the `.+` and then failing to match.

So can Treetop do backtracking like that? If so, how?

I know you can use negation to match "anything other than a `}`." But that's not my intention. Suppose I want to be able to match the string `{ab}c}`. The tokens I want in that case are the opening `{`, a middle string of `ab}c`, and the closing `}`. This is a contrived example, but it becomes very relevant when working with nested expressions like `{a b {c d}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treetop is an implementation of a [Parsing Expression Grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) parser. One of the benefits of PEGs is their combination of flexibility, speed, and memory requirements. However, this balancing act has some tradeoffs.

Quoting from the Wikipedia article:

> The zero-or-more, one-or-more, and optional operators consume zero or more, one or more, or zero or one consecutive repetitions of their sub-expression e, respectively. Unlike in context-free grammars and regular expressions, however, ***these operators always behave greedily***, consuming as much input as possible and ***never backtracking***. […] the expression `(a* a)` will always fail because the first part `(a*)` will never leave any a's for the second part to match.

(Emphasis mine.)

In short: while certain PEG operators can backtrack in an attempt to take another route, the `+` operator cannot.

Instead, in order to match nested sub-expressions, you want to create an alternation between the delimited sub-expression (checked first) followed by the non-expression characters. Something like (untested):

```
grammar TestGrammar
  rule open_close
    '{' contents '}'
  end
  rule contents
    open_close / non_brackets
  end
  rule non_brackets
    # …
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you achieve what I'm describing with a PEG?

Comment: @Jarrett See my edit. Forgive what may be horribly broken syntax; it's been years since I last used Treetop. Note that the Wikipedia entry discusses this specifically (search for "Pascal-style nested comment syntax" on the page).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! What about matching this string: {ab}c}

Comment: Got it. I decided that I just have to regard the first } in {ab}c}, rather than the final one, as the closing bracket. Then, the string c} can be regarded as plain old text. Not exactly what I wanted, but it's a reasonable compromise. I'm not sure, but I'm starting to think this may follow necessarily from the nature of PEGs.